# SSRS 2005 inaccessible after install

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssrs

Hi I've just installed Full SQL 2005, however after I've configured Reporting Services I can't seem to access it.

When I go to http://localhost/reports I get this prompt for a username and password and no mather what I put there it fails with 401.1 Access Denied.

I've disabled kerberos on Reports and ReportServer virtual directories, nothing changed.

I've enabled anonymous auth and got: **Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage.**

When I access from another machine, I get the user and password prompt only once and get the same error.

If I try to access with Management Studio i get this error:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> The underlying connection was closed:
>   An unexpected error occurred on a
>   receive.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.RSClient)
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   (System)
>
> ---
>
> An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host (System)
>
> ---
>
> BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Server is Win 2003 R2 Standard with IIS 6

**UPDATE:** Reporting Services Configuration Manager is all green, I've configured it completely, all accounts are domain accounts, the SQL database server is the same server, the databases are created successfully, if I add a index.html page on Reports virtual directory (directory) I can access it normally (with integrated security enabled).

**UPDATE2:** I've re-downloaded SQL 2005 from microsoft site.
Uninstalled, deleted the remaining folders, Re-installed and I'm still stuck with the same error. I got the KRB_AP_ERR_MODIFIED Kerberos Error on System eventviewer after I reinstalled...

**UPDATE3:** I've downloaded SQL 2005 SP3 and have applied it to SQL, and still have the same problem.
I also noted that on Surface Area Configuration when I click Reporting Services Feature **Windows Integrated Security** I get this error:

> ### TITLE: Surface Area Configuration
>
> The underlying connection was closed:
>   An unexpected error occurred on a
>   receive. (SQLSAC)
>
> ---
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host.
>   (System)
>
> ---
>
> An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host (System)
>
> ---
>
> BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

I Found this [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic611188-150-1.aspx) relating the above error and will try to reinstall IIS.

Can't seem to understand this.
Does anyone have a hint?

**UPDATE 4:** Solved reinstalling IIS with the correct files 
(thank god SQL 2008 doesn't use IIS anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**

It happened that when I installed IIS, I had selected the windows files from a windows server 2003 without any SP's and that was not R2.

And there was a fix in IIS on SP2 that fixed this issue as stated on [this link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic611188-150-3.aspx), so I reinstalled IIS with the W2003R2 files and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

try opening up the ntfs permissions up on the physical directory holding the files. The second one could be your sql install is not accepting remote connections.

On the server you have installed it on try going through the 'Reporting Services Configuration' tool, that should give you a good idea as to what's not configured correctly

Comment: Configuration Manager is all green, except for the keys and unnatended execution account. I've added Full Control on the folders to the domain user running the application pool.

Answer (score 1):

Are you logged in as a local admin on the server when you browse to http://localhosts/reports? After the initial install, only local admins have rights to report server.

Comment: Yep! I'm local admin (but logged as a domain user)